# Interview Question Asked In yahoo

Tags: discrete-mathematics, puzzle

Can you find the smallest positive number such that if you shuffle the digits of the number in a particular order, the shuffled number becomes twice the original number.

Source:
http://gpuzzles.com/mind-teasers/very-hard-maths-riddle/

I understand the answer is $125874 => 251748$

$251748$ is twice the $125874$ and have same digits $1,2,4,5,7$ & $8$

but how to solve this non programmatic ?

Comment: One way is to play fool and answer it in base $2$. The answer becomes $01$, which turns $10$. ;)

Comment: Or in base 8, where $52_8 = 2\cdot 25_8$.

Comment: It's odd that the answer has the same digits as 142857, which is well-known to have the same property.

Comment: Related: [Regularities when $n$ and $2n$ contain the same digits](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/782413/regularities-when-n-and-2n-contain-the-same-digits)

Answer (score 9):

I have a detailed solution to this problem [written up on the math.SE blog](http://math.blogoverflow.com/2014/06/11/when-do-n-and-2n-have-the-same-decimal-digits/).